Do Non-Western Philosophers Do Formal Symbolic Logic?
I'm aware that symbolic logic comes largely from Western analytic philosophy. So I wonder the question above. If non-western (by which I'm mostly thinking of eastern/asian) philosophers work with symbolic logic, how similar/different is it from the one's we're probably more familiar with.

Formalyes, symbolic probably not. See Buddhist logic.
